# Android text cursor in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm writing an application for **android 2.1+**. In one of my activities i have **EditText** with **custom keyboard** (KeyboardView with key mappings in keyboard.xml). Everything works perfect on **android 2.1** ( everything is shown correctly - text cursor is flashing), problems start on **android 2.3.3** where **textcursor in edittext** is visible but `not blinking`, and on **android 3.0+** text cursor is just `invisible` - in both cases keyboard is working correctly. I'm struggling with this problem from couple days... any thoughts would be really helpful.

There is one thing which i should mention earlier. This activity is split into two fragments (android support library), EditText is on one of them, and the keyboard is called from parent activity.

Answer (score 0):

When i faced this problem before, the solution was to disable hardware acceleration on the activity that contains the edit text, by modifying the manifest like this:

```
<activity android:name="activity name" android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me, but thank u for suggestion.